# Does Hibernate (HQL) Support Common Table Expression

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a query that looks like:

```
WITH SubQ AS
    (SELECT elh.encntr_id, elh.location_cd
     FROM encntr_loc_his elh
     WHERE ...)
SELECT e.encntr_id
FROM encounter e
WHERE e.location_cd IN
    (SELECT SubQ.location_cd
     FROM...)
...
```

There are some other details in this query, and the SubQ has been used a lot. My question is, is it possible to put this query in HQL as a named query([namedquery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html))? When I try to do that and compile, it throws an error complaining about **token WITH**:

> Jun 19, 2017 10:38:58 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
>   ERROR: line 1:1: **unexpected token: WITH**
>   Jun 19, 2017 10:38:58 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
>   ERROR: line 1:1: unexpected token: WITH
>   line 1:1: unexpected token: WITH

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate doesn't support common table expressions, but if you want to be able to reference your SubQ query so you don't have to repeat it, you could define it as a view on the database and then map a Hibernate entity to that view.

Comment: I suppose it must be an accepted answer but OP is inactive

Comment: @Hedley There is no direct support, but I was able to run CTE using createNativeQuery API with MySQL 8.014 and Hibernate 5.2.16

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support, but I was able to run CTE using createNativeQuery API with MySQL 8.014 and Hibernate 5.2.16

```
EntityManager entityManager = _entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, YourReturnTypePojo.class);
List<Object[]> a =  q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 6.2 now supports CTE (https://in.relation.to/2023/02/20/hibernate-orm-62-ctes/)